# Android style and theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I am developing an Android app, and I set the `minSDK` to 11 and `targetSDK` to 18. When my app runs on Android 4.0.3 device, it looks like running on pre-ICS. Why?

I mean the `EditText`(s) and other UI elements have non-Holo theme. Please consider following images. I see this in design which should be viewed same in run-time:

[image]

but I see this in the device (4.0.3):

[image]

manifest and style (sections has dependncy to the issue)

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
 </style>   

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: you should apply theme to these edittexts and buttons to make it consistent across all platforms. try this http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Post your styles.xml file and your Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android developers the theme of the views will be compatible according to the minimum sdk version.

Actually in the graphical layout in the eclipse not rendered to the minimum sdk version.
But when u comes for the real device the compatibility comes.

The  solution will be you could use your own themes for each views or you can go for this..

Check [Holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com) or [Theme generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

Answer (score 0):

The layout you can see on your layout files graphical layout is set as you set them.

If you are using eclipse you can change the apptheme on the graphical layout page. There is option for different level of API ,App theme,Device.
You can experiment on them to get a clear view of your problem